# Grails - Duplicate key error

Tags: postgresql, grails, primary-key

I am using postgres DB and I imported data from csv file. When I try to add new entry from Grails create page, it gives

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "course_pkey" Detail: Key (id)=(34) already exists.
```

I have 697 entries already in the table. How can I have Grails continue to save the entry with id=698?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should check PK types for your domain i.e. INCREMENTAL. Also, make sure that the objects that you are adding should not have id set as id will itself be decided iff null.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to use a [`SERIAL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) type for your primary key in the Postgres database. A `SERIAL` type auto-increments and sets a default value to the next value. [Grails defaults](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html) to using [Hibernate's `native` (see section 5.1.2.2.1)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-declaration-id) id generator strategy, which will use the underlying database. Then you need to simply not specify the `id` in your domain instance and let the id get generated.

However, if you need to do your exact use case of trying the next id value, you can use a try catch block.

```
try {
    course.save(flush: true)
} catch (DuplicateKeyException e) { // Not sure what the exact exception is
    course.id++
    course.save(flush: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check de id secuen from hibernate

```
select * from hibernate_sequence ;
```

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/primary-key-constraint-violations-td1356352.html

For PostgreSQL, you can edit the field last_value in the pgAdmin